# Kotlin: How to resolve function name clashes when one interface defines a suspend function and the other does not

Tags: kotlin

I had the following problem and was able to resolve the problem by renaming the functions. I am finding myself struggling doing that without my workaround...

How is the following implementation possible without modifying the interfaces:

```
interface A {
    fun test() { }
}


interface B {
   suspend fun test()
}

class C : A, B {
  suspend fun test(){ // Change that line as you wish
    // Implementation
}
```

Notes: I know of the [Kotlin Wiki](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html#resolving-overriding-conflicts). But this is more difficult as IntelliJ didn't show that C is a valid implementation of A.

(My problem as far as I know is that one of the interface defines a suspend function and the other does not. My gut feeling is that a non-suspending function should be ok with being implemented as a suspending function, but there does not seem to be such a relation)

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: That's ambiguous, how would the compiler know when to call `test()` with suspend modifier, and when to call without one? (Although at JVM level both functions are different, but from the point of view of the Kotlin compiler they're the same)

Comment: If that worked, how would you satisfy A's requirement for a `test()` method without a `suspend` modifier?

Comment: I think some kind of resolution should be possible. Otherwise dealing with Interfaces might be a big problem in the future. "Worst case" let me define a suspend and a normal function with the same name (which does not really make sense to me)

Comment: But it isn't letting you define a normal function and a suspend function with the same name.  Isn't that the point of the question? - It's the same situation as where you can't define two methods that have the same name and parameters but return different types. - It's as @AnimeshSahu says...the issue is that the compiler can't know which one you mean to call.

Comment: Do we have a kind of best practice to avoid that - or is that a case of bad luck? Usually you cannot change interfaces easily....

Comment: I think the best practice would be that interfaces that are expected to be implemented by monolithic classes should have highly descriptive function names to avoid the possibility of signature clashes.